# Android Google Analytics v2 Tracker.setThrottlingEnabled(boolean throttlingEnabled)

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can't find any documentation about:

```
Tracker.setThrottlingEnabled(boolean throttlingEnabled)
```

In [Google Analytics v2](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced) documentation.

Can some one explain me what is this method for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT]: My previous answer said things that are not really correct. Updated answer below:

The method you mentioned is not a supported method and **will be** removed from a future version. Please don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can I ask where you found the answer?

Comment: I am an engineer at Google and work closely with the team that publishes the sdk. I updated my answer after talking to my colleagues.

Comment: It will be great if Google Analytics engineers will remove it from next Google Analytics Android SDK.Thank you.